# Outer div does not expand with inner div

Tags: html, css

I have got a set of HTML webpages that use the HTML template as below and each HTML page has a different amount of content. All HTML pages use the same CSS file which is also given below.

So as I said, the content of each page is different and I want the outer div (`#main`) to resize automatically based on the content (`#content`).

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            Content goes here
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            Created by Cleopatra Masy © August, 2015<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background:url('/images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:cover;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
}

#main {
box-shadow:6px 0 15px -4px rgba(31,73,125,0.8), -6px 0 8px -4px rgba(31,73,125,0.8);
position:relative;
height:1000px;
width:980px;
margin:0 auto;
}

#content {
font-weight: normal;
min-height:655px;
margin-right:20px;
margin-left:220px;
width:740px;
position:absolute;
margin-top:105px;
}

#footer {
background:url('/images/footer-back.png') repeat-x left top;
font-size:17px;
color:#FFF;
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
width:980px;
line-height:30px;
vertical-align:middle;
bottom:0;
}
```

I have tried the following which haven't seemed to work...

**Attempt 1**

I set the min-height of `#main` to 1000px but this did not do anything.

**Attempt 2**

I set the height of `#main` to 100% but this caused the box-shadows and footer to disappear.

NB: I have also tried looking over previous questions but none of them have seemed to work for me. In most situations the box-shadows and footer disappears.

Please also note that this is a new issue and I require serious help.

Any help will be grateful.

Thanks,
Cleopatra Masy

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do but any outer `<div/>` will automaticly resize based on the it's contents as long as you don't start messing with its size. Prove: http://jsfiddle.net/bxada3fb/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `#content` is positioned absolutely. 
Thus it does not take up any space.

The code you've included suggests that it should be save to remove the position property of `#content` altogether. Just make sure to set the `min-height` of  `#main` instead of `height` such that the element can actually grow.
To avoid overlapping of the content and footer you should also add a padding to the bottom of `#main`.

```js
var lines = 0;
var content = document.getElementById('content');
content.addEventListener('click', function() {
  lines++;
  content.innerHTML += '<br>Line ' + lines;
});
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#content {
  background-color: green;
}

#footer {
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="content">
    Click to add line.
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    &copy; 2015 ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. Here's a http://jsfiddle.net/u1L9nz6o/:

```
#main {
  box-shadow:6px 0 15px -4px rgba(31,73,125,0.8), -6px 0 8px -4px rgba(31,73,125,0.8);
  position:relative;
  height:1000px;
  width:980px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: normal;
  min-height:655px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```